# Haproxy load balancer does not work from centos7

Tags: https, load-balancer, haproxy

I am trying to set up HAproxy load balancer on centos 7, however I am unable to get it working. From services it sais that it is running, but the stats page wont open and also it does not direct to anywhere. What I am trying to do is use it as a load balancer to move traffic to first or second server that is secured by https. The HAproxy itself does not need to be secured by https and currently is not. Right now I have the following config:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#--------------------------------------------------------------------- global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log 127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#--------------------------------------------------------------------- defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000
    stats enable
        stats auth haproxy:haproxy
        stats uri /haproxy
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#--------------------------------------------------------------------- frontend  front
        redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
        bind *:80
        mode http
        default_backend app
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#--------------------------------------------------------------------- backend app
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1rnHost:localhost
    server s1 192.168.14.65:443 check
    server s2  192.168.14.200:443 check

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#--------------------------------------------------------------------- listen stats *:8080
        mode http
        log global
        maxconn 10
        clitimeout 100s
        srvtimeout 100s
        contimeout 100s
        timeout queue 100s

stats refresh 30s stats show-node
```

the logs only show the following:

```
Aug 21 16:06:00 localhost haproxy[11177]: Proxy front started.
Aug 21 16:06:00 localhost haproxy[11177]: Proxy app started.
Aug 21 16:10:08 localhost haproxy[11275]: Proxy front started.
Aug 21 16:10:08 localhost haproxy[11275]: Proxy app started.
Aug 21 16:10:08 localhost haproxy[11275]: Proxy stats started.
```

...
but nothing more useful. 
When I go to any of the ip addresses described in the config file when service is running I get absolutely nothing (timed out).

I also tried removing timeouts, but it did not help. I got these messages with no timeout:

```
Aug 21 16:52:27 localhost haproxy[11413]: Server app/s1 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 invalid response, info: "<15><03><03>", check duration: 399ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
Aug 21 16:52:28 localhost haproxy[11413]: Server app/s2 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 invalid response, info: "<15><03><03>", check duration: 227ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now. The main culprict was the firewalld that centos7 ran, that blocked all of my needed ports. Also I needed to modify my config a bit, so it would forward to ssh backend. Final config looked like this:

```
[root@rimilb ~]# cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log 127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    maxconn                 3000
    stats enable
        stats auth haproxy:haproxy
        stats uri /haproxy
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  front
        bind 192.168.14.251:80
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
        default_backend app
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server s1 192.168.14.65:443 weight 1 maxconn 100 check ssl verify none
    server s2  192.168.14.200:443 weight 1 maxconn 100 check ssl verify none

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
listen stats *:8080
        mode http
        log global
        maxconn 10
        clitimeout 100s
        srvtimeout 100s
        contimeout 100s
        timeout queue 100s

stats refresh 30s
stats show-node
```